GitKraken shows empty screen after changing CPU
When I changed my CPU from i5-4440 to i5-12400F and reinstalled Windows 10 Professional x64, GitKraken doesn't work correctly - nothing shows in screen.
empty screen
I reinstalled it, tried various versions, changed graphic settings, compatibility - no results.
My configuration: i5-12400F, RTX 3060, Windows 10 Pro

GitKraken is a Java app.  You might try reinstalling your Java runtime environment.

Not a git question

Even less [github]…

Tried reinstalling JRE - doesn't work
